# Критическая ошибка wordpress при переходе к настройкам сайта

Tags: php, wordpress

При нажатии кнопки настроить на панели wordpress возникает ошибка. Вот что оно выдает в режиме debug[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При смене темы возникает похожая проблема.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также в режиме debug в консоле отображаются эти ошибки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам текст ошибок перевести или каковы Ваши ожидания от того что Вы показали нам эти скрины?

Comment: У Вас на сайте используется Elementor + WooCommerce и еще ряд плагинов. Если перейдете по ссылочке [What are Elementor’s system requirements?](https://elementor.com/help/requirements/#elementor-toc__heading-anchor-3) то увидите там нечто большее, чем 128 мегабайт (512 MB recommended).